# Parsing and Iterating over URL List in Python

Tags: python

```
website_list = [
    'https://www.zillow.com/62347390?location=Chicago%2N%23253',
    'https://www.zillow.com/82983250?location=Boston%3B%53324',
    'https://www.zillow.com/12917837?location=Miami%7K%26345',
]
```

How does one create a python function (e.g. `city_finder()`) such that we get the following output when given `website_list` as input?

```
>>> city_finder(website_list)
['Chicago', 'Boston', 'Miami']
```

Comment: You could use a simple regular expression like `location=([^%]+)` and grab the first group, see https://regex101.com/r/aSJxn7/1

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers assume that the format of the URLs will not change. Using regular expressions does not account for unexpected URL forms.

To handle changes in the URL format, use the `urllib.parse` module, whose documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).

Namely, use the `urlparse()` function, which can parse a URL into its components. The component you want is the "query component," which is exposed by `urlparse()` as a dictionary. The value associated with the `location` key will be a list containing, for example, `'Chicago%2N%23253'`. Finally, extract the substring before the first `%`.

Here's a code snippet:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

def city_finder(links)
    cities = []
    for url in links:
        query = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)
        cities.append(query['location'][0].split('%')[0])
    return cities
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.find() to find the index location of "location=" and of the "%" following the name of the city. Use a list compehension to loop through the url list:

```
def city_finder(website_list)
    return [site[site.find("location=")+9:site.find("%")] for site in website_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re` module to find word following `location=` from each item in `website_list`. Use `append` to add retrieved location to `city` list and `return` it.

```
import re
website_list = ['https://www.zillow.com/62347390?location=Chicago%2N%23253', 'https://www.zillow.com/82983250?location=Boston%3B%53324', 'https://www.zillow.com/12917837?location=Miami%7K%26345']
regexp = re.compile("location=(.*)%")
city = []
def city_finder(website_list):
    for lists in website_list:
        city.append((regexp.search(lists).group(1).split('%')[0]))
    return(city)
print city_finder(website_list)
```

Outputs:

```
['Chicago', 'Boston', 'Miami']
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you could use

```
import re

website_list = [
    'https://www.zillow.com/62347390?location=Chicago%2N%23253',
    'https://www.zillow.com/82983250?location=Boston%3B%53324',
    'https://www.zillow.com/12917837?location=Miami%7K%26345',
]

def city_finder(lst=None):
    rx = re.compile(r'location=([^%]+)')
    return [city.group(1) 
            for item in lst 
            for city in [rx.search(item)]
            if city]

print(city_finder(website_list))
```

Which yields

```
['Chicago', 'Boston', 'Miami']
```